# Clickhouse installation for mac fails: "AppleClang is not supported, you should install clang from brew."

Tags: macos, cmake, clang, clickhouse

I'm following this [instructions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/es/development/build-osx/).
When I run the following command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=`which clang++` -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=`which clang`
```

I'm having this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/tools.cmake:20 (message):
  AppleClang is not supported, you should install clang from brew.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/myuser/ClickHouse/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Any ideas of what is happening?

Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)

cmake version 3.18.4

macOs Catalina 10.15.7

thanks!

Comment: It says AppleClang not supported, maybe this helps https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8990#issuecomment-588277342

Comment: Do you really need to compile CH yourself? You can use CH in docker or download compiled CH binary.

Comment: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/development/build-osx/

Answer (score -1):

I've installed clang again and it worked. Followed this https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/24/installing-llvm-clang-on-osx/